# "How is he in himself?"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[*Me Before You*](http://www.readromancebook.net/books/Me_Before_You/50.html)

> ‘How is he in himself? Have you …  have you come up with any other
>   ideas?

One paralyzed man wanted to commit suicide. This girl (man's nursing assistant) told that to the guy's mother. His mother asked this question.

What does "How is he in himself?" means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cambridge English Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/himself)

> **in himself**  (U.K. informal)
>   used when describing or asking about a man's state of mind when he is physically ill.
>   *He's well enough in himself - he just can't shake this cold off.*

So it is more specific than saying "How is he?"
You could answer that with his physical, emotional, and/or mental condition.

But "How is he in himself?" is specifically asking about his mental condition.